# TFS Client API - Query to get work items linked to a specific file?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, tfs

We are writing a custom tool using TFS client APIs, to connect to TFS, to fetch work items for a project etc.

---

We are querying the work item store, using WIQL.

Given a fully qualified filename, what is the easiest way to get a list of work items that have change sets which contain the specified file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is an easy way to do the query that you are requesting using the TFS API.  I know that you definately cannot do it using WIQL.  I think, using the API, you would have to iterate over all the work items - get the changeset links in them and then look in each changeset for the file path that you are after.  This is obviously not much use.

You could get that data using the TFS Data Warehouse database however.  This information will lag behind the live operational store information because the warehouse only gets updated periodically - but will allow you to track things by the folder/file dimension pretty easily.

Answer (score 3):

This little code snippet will get you a collection of work items given a TFS server name and a project.. It also filters out work items in the deleted state.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;

    namespace EngineTFSAutomation
    {
        class TFSHelper
        {
            static public WorkItemCollection QueryWorkItems(string server, string projectname)
            {
                TeamFoundationServer tfs = TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer(server);
                WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)tfs.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));
                Project p = workItemStore.Projects[projectname];
                string wiqlQuery = "Select * from Issue where [System.TeamProject] = '"+projectname+"'";
                wiqlQuery += " and [System.State] <> 'Deleted'";
                wiqlQuery+= " order by ID";
                WorkItemCollection witCollection = workItemStore.Query(wiqlQuery);
                return witCollection;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just realized you are looking for a way to get a list of all work items that have changesets affecting a specific file.

Comment: well the WIQL query will give you all the work items, then I suppose you can iterate each work item that has links. If the links are changesets you can see if the changesets contain the file in question. I'll see if I can code something like that up, I'll revise my answer later.

Comment: I was trying the code you've provided, and got the warning that the TeamFoundationServer class is deprecated in TFS 2010. I used  `TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(server)); tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();` which works, but the query seem to run forever (and does not come to an end). Do you have a hint?

Answer (score 1):

For **TFS 2012**

```
    Uri tfsUri = new Uri("http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8080/tfs2012");
    TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer =TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(tfsUri);                  
    ReadOnlyCollection<CatalogNode> collectionNodes = configurationServer.CatalogNode.QueryChildren(new[] {CatalogResourceTypes.ProjectCollection },false,CatalogQueryOptions.None);   

    foreach (CatalogNode collectionNode in collectionNodes)
    {
        // Use the InstanceId property to get the team project collection
        Guid collectionId = new Guid(collectionNode.Resource.Properties["InstanceId"]);
        TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = configurationServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(collectionId);

        WorkItemStore workItemStore = (WorkItemStore)teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(WorkItemStore));

        string query = "SELECT [System.Id] FROM WorkItems where [Assigned to]=@Me";
        WorkItemCollection queryResults = workItemStore.Query(query);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For TFS 2013 following code works to access TFS project Information:

```
var tfsUri = new Uri("http://tfs.xxx.xxx.com:8080/tfs/myCollection");
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri);
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();
var iis = tfs.GetService<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore>();
// here access to a particular Project with its name
var uriWithGuid = iis.Projects["My project name"].Uri;
```